# Visual Studio 2012 crashes and restarts every time I run a test

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a unit test project in my solution and every time I run a test, my vs2012 crashes and restarts itself.

Basically the test finishes and then a popup shows up saying Microsoft Visual Studio has stopped working, then another box comes up saying MS VS is restarting.

Has anyone run into this problem also and does anyone know how to fix this?  I really appreciate any help on this.

Edit: I have tried to uninstall plugins as well as reset my vs environment, no help.  Whenever I open the Test Explorer up, this happens too.

Edit: I thought it was Web Essential plugin, because it worked after I uninstalled it and stopped working when I installed it back.  Now, the problem came back, I don't know how but it came back without the plugin installed.

Comment: Attach a debugger to it from another VS instance and check where it stops

Comment: what are your tests doing?  Is it possible that the tests are doing something in particular that causes this?

Comment: Just found that whenever I open the Test Explorer up, this happens too.  I'm not doing much in the test, something simple like Assert.IsTrue(true); would hang it.

Comment: Have you installed the latest update of visual studio 2012?

Comment: I don't know if this is related or not, but I can't use Test Explorer either.  Visual Studio doesn't crash for me, but my tests fails if I use Test Explorer to run them and pass if I use TestDriven.  Something weird with the dll references.  What testing framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using the built-in test framework that comes with VS.  @Jehof yes I installed the new update2. It crashes regardless I use the test explorer or not, very frustrating.  I'm doing a repair on my VS right now and see if it can fix it.

Comment: I figured out, it's the Sandcastle plugin that causes this entire issue, uninstall it and vs runs fine with tests again.

Answer (score 3):

Try running Visual Studio as administrator

Comment: My VS 12 crashes since yesterday even though I always "run as admin"

Answer (score 1):

Try delete everything in this registry location and restart VS:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ExtensionManager\EnabledExtensions
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem lately - VS2012 was crashing when trying to start unit tests and on opening the test explorer.

The error was an invalid hostname (`inner-exception message: hostname could not be parsed` (it won't say what's the hostname, though));

What fixed it:

I changed my computer's name, so it no longer contained illegal/reserved characters when used in an http url.

You will probably have to update some of your used connections (`tfs / sqlexpress`).

Hope this helps.